# After render, element with jquery wrapper is not reconized

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have a layoutView which stores focused element so:

```
this.model.searchBookingTriggerElement = document.activeElement;
```

The layoutView is reRendered and I try to trigger the following:

```
onRender: function() {
    var self = this;
    _.defer(function() {
        if (self.model.searchBookingTriggerElement) {
            $(self.model.searchBookingTriggerElement).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

This doesn't work, which I can't understand since the element seems to be the correct one.

When I do `console.log(self.model.searchBookingTriggerElement);` I get:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn button item-component btn-medium btn-green">Buscar</button>
```

If I select it directly with a simple

```
$("button").hide();
```

It works as expected (hides the element), why isn't jquery recognizing the selected button element?

---

One clue I did find is that when I hover

```
<button type="submit" class="btn button item-component btn-medium btn-green" style="display: none;">Buscar</button>
```

in the develeper tools it doesn't paint it on the screen, meaning it is not associated with it.

Is this because it was re-rendered and now it is, another object so to say? How can I avoid that?

It even works if I do:

```
$("." + $(self.model.searchBookingTriggerElement).attr("class").split(" ").join(".")).hide();
```

Comment: The behavior you're seeing suggests that `searchBookingTriggerElement` is not the same element as `$('button')[0]`. If you are re-rendering then I would expect all the old DOM elements to get killed and then replaced with new ones. How to fix? Probably you should store the selected state as a view property or maybe a model attribute, storing a DOM element as a property on a model is, um, rather bizarre.

Comment: @muistooshort hey, thanks! I'm not sure what you're suggesting, anyway I see it, I would have get the attribute and class, and select it, but I'm not quite sure this would work since I don't know which element will be at focus neither whether it will have a class or id etc. So I want to select the dom element itself, thanks for the suggestion of not using a model property, I will stop using it, but I'm not sure how this will help since I still have to select it, and even if bizzare, I do have the object (even though it doesn't exist) so getting it from an attribute won't change much afaik

Comment: Re-rendering should effectively do `some_el.html(new_html)` and that will destroy everything in `some_el` before creating new nodes, you'll end up with a reference to a DOM element that is no longer on the page, that's why  doing things to `searchBookingTriggerElement` doesn't affect the page. Why don't you have a "selected" attribute on your models or similar? That way you're not trying to store state in the DOM, the DOM will just display state that is stored elsewhere.

Comment: `this.model.searchBookingTriggerElement = document.activeElement` how/when are you executing this code..? Can ypu post a [mcve]..?

Comment: I think you should also remove the "defer" function and move the code to hide element in the "onAttach" callback instead of the "onRender".

Answer (score 0):

I think the comments are pretty clear, your selected element is gone once you re-render. I assume you are the one creating the layout, so perhaps you can assign a unique id to each element that could be selected, so each time you render all you need is the id.

```
this.searchBookingTriggerElement = document.activeElement.id;
```

I left out the defer but you can add it in -

```
onRender: function() {
  var self = this;
  if (self.searchBookingTriggerElement) {
    $('#' + self.searchBookingTriggerElement).hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, why do you need to re-render? You could hide it without re-rendering and since it is a layout if there are things that need replacing, you can replace them without re-rendering.